# MAMP setup will now exit and the existing map installation will not be removed

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I deleted MAMP cause' I needed to free the space on my hard-drive and now I want to install it again, but I can't. I keep getting the mistake 'MAMP setup will now exit and the existing map installation will not be removed'. I thought that I still have some MAMP-files on my PC, but I don't. Can't figure out what's wrong and need some help!

Comment: restart your pc and see if the problem still exists

Comment: I did, like 2 times. Nothing changed.

Comment: I think you still have some references in your registry or the like.

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same problem. I tried this method and it was solved.
Open the control panel>programs>programs and features>there comes the list of programs,find mamp and right click on it and click on 'uninstall'.
After getting uninstalled you can try to install it again. Then it works .